# uv coordinates to world map coordinates

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-saver, world, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working with turtlebot and I've built and saved a map using gmapping. I'm wondering if there is a funtion that transforms uv coordinates from map picture into world map coordinates. Or if there isn't what would be the simplest way to do so.  Thank you for your anwsers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207388/uv-coordinates-to-world-map-coordinates/) by [simejanko](https://answers.ros.org/users/22210/simejanko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found resolution(which tells you m per pixel- 0.05 in my case) and origin parameters in map.yaml file which can be used for conversion.

---

Originally posted by [simejanko](https://answers.ros.org/users/22210/simejanko/) with karma: 1 on 2015-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0